# How do I change a WAV to txt file of time vs amplitude?

Tags: audio, wav, data-conversion

I want to use the file input feature of LTSpice to simulate a circuit using a real world bit of audio.  I need the data in a time vs amplitude version but not sure which software package can do this for me.  Audacity can convert the MP3 to WAV but from what I see can't do it to a headerless text file.

So a .WAV file to a two column text file of time/amplitude.

Any ideas for a free way of doing it?

Comment: You're reading this response using software capable of the task. Edit your question to provide samples of the input and expected output and you'll receive an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick'n'nasty implementation using javascript.

I'll leave it as an exercise to convert the result string to a Blob which can be easily downloaded, as will I leave channel selection, stereo results and the ability to select a small portion of the audio track for processing.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

var audioCtx;

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    byId('fileInput').addEventListener('change', onFileInputChangedGeneric, false);
}

function onFileInputChangedGeneric(evt)
{
    // load file if chosen
    if (this.files.length != 0)
    {
        var fileObj = this.files[0];
        loadAndTabulateAudioFile( fileObj, byId('output') );
    }
    // clear output otherwise
    else
        byId('output').textContent = '';
}

// processes channel 0 only
//
//  creates a string that represents a 2 column table, where each row contains the time and amplitude of a sample
//  columns are tab seperated
function loadAndTabulateAudioFile( fileObj, tgtElement )
{
    var a = new FileReader();
    a.onload = loadedCallback;
    a.readAsArrayBuffer( fileObj );
    function loadedCallback(evt)
    {
        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(evt.target.result, onDataDecoded);
    }
    function onDataDecoded(buffer)
    {
        //console.log(buffer);
        var leftChannel = buffer.getChannelData(0);

        //var rightChannel = buffer.getChannelData(1);
        console.log("# samples: " + buffer.length);
        console.log(buffer);

        var result = '';
        var i, n = buffer.length, invSampleRate = 1.0 / buffer.sampleRate;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            var curResult = (invSampleRate*i).toFixed(8) + "\t" + leftChannel[i] + "\n";
            result += curResult;
        }
        tgtElement.textContent = result;
    }
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Select audio file: <input type='file' id='fileInput'/></label>
    <hr>
    <pre id='output'></pre>
</body>
</html>
```